# Verifying a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $X = \{x, y\}$ be a set with associative and commutative operations $+$, $\cdot$ defined as follows
>   \begin{align}
> x+x&=x,       &  x+y&=y,      &   y+y&=x \\
> x\cdot x&=x,  &  x\cdot y&=x, &   y\cdot y&=y.
> \end{align}
>   Verify that X with the operations is a field

So I know I have to verify additive identity and inverse, multiplicative identity and inverse, and distributivity,not sure how to check this here though?

Comment: If $x+x=x$ and $x+y=y$, what's the additive identity?  By the way, there's only one field with two elements up to isomorphism.  Are you familiar with $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I am not, what is it?

Comment: integers modulo $2$ comprise a field with elements represented by $0$ and $1$

Comment: what would that have to do with this though?

Answer (score 1):

$x$ and $y$ are the only elements in the set. We see that $x+x=x$ and $x+y=y$, so (together with commutativity of $+$) we find $x$ as the additive identity. Similarly, we get $y$ as the multiplicative identity.

Checking inverses, we find that $-x=x$, $-y=y$ and $y^{-1}=y$ ($x$ excluded from the multiplicative inverse check, being the additive identity). Finally, it should be easy to check via casework (substitute $x,y$ into $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$) that distributivity is satisfied. Hence the given structure is a field.

Comment: how would i do that if there is just x, y for something that needs a,b, and c?

Comment: @BOIDOI There are $8$ cases here. Verify each one.

Comment: isn't everything but distributivity verified already from what you did? or do you have to show it for every case?

Comment: @BOIDOI I did everything but distributivity explicitly. The distributivity is just casework and I am inviting you to do that.

Comment: aren't there only 6 cases here?

Comment: @BOIDOI Yes, if you take commutativity into account.

Comment: but how would you show distributivity in any of these if they aren't in the format of a*(b+c)? How could I even show distributivity for something like x+x=x?

Comment: @BOIDOI You _substitute_ $x,y$ for each of $a,b,c$, and verify that both sides are equal.

Comment: So like x(x+x) = xx+xx
x(x+y) = xx+xy
x(y+y) = xy+xy
y(x+x) = yx+yx
y(x+y) = yx+yy
y(y+y) = yy+yy

Comment: @BOIDOI Yes, all of them.